# having problem with query in JPA using Wildfly/Hibernate java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am attempting the following query:

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="miscPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public ClientCompanyDAO() {
    }
    

    public List <ClientCompany> findAllClientCompanies() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select c from ClientCompany c");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

When I run it I get the error: SQLException: No database selected from the getResultList method.

The entity is setup like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="clientcompany")
public class ClientCompany extends Company implements Serializable {
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="miscPU">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/misc</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="autojobsPU">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/autojobs</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The java:/jdbc/misc datasource has been created and pings successfully on Wildfly 19. The url on the datasource is jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/misc.

What could I be missing?

UPDATE: As requested, here is the stack trace. IJ had to delete some of it because of stack overflow limits on number of lines. It repeats several times presumably because it makes several attempts to complete the query.

```
:22:49,897 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-001471: Interceptor method init defined on class com.lingosys.user.ClientCreatorBean is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
    at com.lingosys.user.ClientCreatorBean.init(ClientCreatorBean.java:0)
  StackTrace
13:22:50,107 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP08 for context '/LingoMavenApps'
13:22:54,403 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/LingoMavenApps' for server 'default-server'
13:22:54,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "LingoMavenApps.war" (runtime-name : "LingoMavenApps.war")
[2020-09-14 01:22:54,465] Artifact LingoMavenApps:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2020-09-14 01:22:54,465] Artifact LingoMavenApps:war: Deploy took 12,006 milliseconds
13:24:20,774 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-3) created new TransactionScopedEntityManager for unit name=LingoMavenApps.war#miscPU
13:24:20,834 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-3) default task-3:transaction scoped EntityManager [LingoMavenApps.war#miscPU]: created entity manager session Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a801b9:5dfa9ce2:5f5fd10e:11 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)
13:24:20,850 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-3) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:24:20,912 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-3) createQuery took 133ms
13:24:20,917 DEBUG [jboss.jdbc.spy] (default task-3) java:/jdbc/misc [DataSource] getConnection()
13:24:20,926 DEBUG [jboss.jdbc.spy] (default task-3) java:/jdbc/misc [Connection] prepareStatement(select clientcomp0_.id as id1_1_, clientcomp0_.addPMSurchargeforDocTrans as addPMSur8_1_, clientcomp0_.billingEmail as billing14_1_, clientcomp0_.billingInstructions as billing13_1_, clientcomp0_.checkKnowledgeMgt as checkKn19_1_, clientcomp0_.clientPONumber as clientP18_1_, clientcomp0_.commissionType as commissi7_1_, clientcomp0_.createdBy as created20_1_, clientcomp0_.docTransPricingScheme as docTrans4_1_, clientcomp0_.dtBucket as dtBucket6_1_, clientcomp0_.guid as guid3_1_, clientcomp0_.legalEntity as legalEn15_1_, clientcomp0_.legalEntityCompany as legalEn16_1_, clientcomp0_.lingoClientNumber as lingoCl21_1_, clientcomp0_.llsClientID as llsClie12_1_, clientcomp0_.name as name2_1_, clientcomp0_.passTradosLeveraging as passTra10_1_, clientcomp0_.paymentTerms as paymentT5_1_, clientcomp0_.prospect as prospec11_1_, clientcomp0_.specialInstructions as special17_1_, clientcomp0_.usLinguistsRequired as usLingui9_1_ from clientcompany clientcomp0_)
13:24:20,954 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) SQL Error: 1046, SQLState: 3D000
13:24:20,954 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) No database selected
13:24:20,955 DEBUG [jboss.jdbc.spy] (default task-3) java:/jdbc/misc [Connection] isClosed()
13:24:20,955 DEBUG [jboss.jdbc.spy] (default task-3) java:/jdbc/misc [Connection] isClosed()
13:24:20,955 DEBUG [jboss.jdbc.spy] (default task-3) java:/jdbc/misc [Connection] clearWarnings()
13:24:20,955 DEBUG [jboss.jdbc.spy] (default task-3) java:/jdbc/misc [Connection] close()
13:24:20,961 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-3) transaction association counter = 0 for default task-3:transaction scoped EntityManager [LingoMavenApps.war#miscPU]: 
13:24:20,962 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-3) transaction association counter = 1 for default task-3:transaction scoped EntityManager [LingoMavenApps.war#miscPU]: 
13:24:20,962 TRACE [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-3) transaction association counter = 0 for default task-3:transaction scoped EntityManager [LingoMavenApps.war#miscPU]: 
13:24:20,963 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-3) default task-3:transaction scoped EntityManager [LingoMavenApps.war#miscPU]: closing entity managersession
13:24:20,965 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-3) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ClientCompanyDAO for method public java.util.List com.lingosys.jpa.ClientCompanyDAO.findAllClientCompanies(): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:374)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at 
<deleted>
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at com.lingosys.jpa.ClientCompanyDAO.findAllClientCompanies(ClientCompanyDAO.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:249)
    ... 150 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2265)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2028)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
    ... 180 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 195 more
13:24:20,974 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3) Error Rendering View[/user/creator/company.xhtml]: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void com.lingosys.user.ClientCreatorBean.init() throws java.lang.Exception on com.lingosys.user.ClientCreatorBean@5056953a
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:122)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.bean.IsolatedForwardingBean.create(IsolatedForwardingBean.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:694)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
    at 
<delete>
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:374)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:627)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at com.lingosys.jpa.ClientCompanyDAO$$$view1.findAllClientCompanies(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at com.lingosys.jpa.ClientCompanyDAO$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findAllClientCompanies(Unknown Source)
    at com.lingosys.user.ClientCreatorBean.init(ClientCreatorBean.java:114)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at com.lingosys.jpa.ClientCompanyDAO.findAllClientCompanies(ClientCompanyDAO.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:249)
    ... 150 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2265)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2028)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
    ... 180 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 195 more

``
```

Comment: Hi, can you update the question with the full stack trace? It may provide hints to the problem!

Comment: As requested I appended the full stack trace to the end of my original post.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot make something out of it. My suggestion is to try to connect to that database using a simple `main` client. Do it from the same machine/VM/container that is running WildFly! Use the exact same DB URL & credentials. What is happening? One more thing: double check the JAR files that get bundled in your application, make sure no system-provided library (e.g. Hibernate) has sneaked in.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your data-source is pointing to the target database. If you're using MySQL and you want to use the `my-database` database, for example, you could specify it in the JDBC connection URL like the following: `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my-database`.

Since you mentioned you're using Wildfly, check your data-source settings in your `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml` file.

Comment: I checked the datasource. It is pointing to the correct JDBC URL.

Comment: Can you copy-paste your data-source configuration?

Comment: Here is the datasource configuration minus passwords.

Comment: ``` <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/misc" pool-name="misc" spy="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/misc</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password></password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I sent a native query with "use misc" to try to force setting a database. I learned that it was trying to pick up fields that were not in the MySQL table apparently it does this for bean properties of the entity regardless of whether or not you give them a @Column annotation. Did not have this problem with native Hibernate 3.